# Save an arraylist of Strings to shared preferences

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

What is the best way to save an `ArrayList` of strings to `SharedPreferences` in API level 8? The only way i can think of now is to save all of the strings into one string separated by commas and save it that way. But I don't know if there is a maximum size for strings.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you to save the arraylist as Internal Storage File in Android. For example for a arraylist named `text_lines`:

Internal storage File IO (Writing) :

```
try {
   //Modes: MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE
   FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("lines.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
   DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
   dout.writeInt(text_lines.size()); // Save line count
   for(String line : text_lines) // Save lines
      dout.writeUTF(line);
   dout.flush(); // Flush stream ...
   dout.close(); // ... and close.
}
catch (IOException exc) { exc.printStackTrace(); }
```

Interal storage File IO (Reading) :

```
FileInputStream input = openFileInput("lines.txt"); // Open input stream
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
int sz = din.readInt(); // Read line count
for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) { // Read lines
   String line = din.readUTF();
   text_lines.add(line);
}
din.close();
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up using, I'm sure other answers would work too

Comment: Good, it would be easier instead of make things complicated with sharedprefereces in your case. Good luck!

Comment: Eventhough this will work, shared preference has a peculiar property of persisting till the app uninstallation, but on the other hand if we are using SD card storage, we will have to explicitly delete the files.

Comment: Totally agree with @SreekanthKarumanaghat , using `shared pref` is preferable as compared to `files` for these things.

Comment: @eRaisedToX Please up-vote the comment if you agree, this answer actually though serves the purpose, doesn't actually answer  the original question.

Answer (score 26):

If you can guarantee your `String`s in `ArrayList` don't contain comma, you can simply use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
...
editor.putString(PREF_KEY_STRINGS, TextUtils.join(",", list));
```

and to read the list

```
String serialized = prefs.getString(PREF_KEY_STRINGS, null);
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ","));
```

You are limited by the memory of the device. It's good practice to use background thread to read/write shared preferences.

Comment: Nice approach, simple.

Comment: What does serialized do?

Comment: Don't forget Arrays.asList gives a fixed sized ArrayList that will throw UnsupportedOperation if you try to add something to it. You can change it like new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ","))).

Answer (score 3):

There is a method, `putStringSet()`, in `SharedPreferences.Editor`, which you can take advantage of if your strings are a `Set`. (That is, no duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an api (like level 8) where you cant use put/getStringSet(), then this is a possible solution, but this is **very expensive** and **not flexible** if you want to store bigger lists. I mean creating a map like datastructure for a simple array-like structure creates a huge overhead, if preformance is important.

To save it:

```
public static void writeList(Context context, List<String> list, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    int size = prefs.getInt(prefix+"_size", 0);

    // clear the previous data if exists
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        editor.remove(prefix+"_"+i);

    // write the current list
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        editor.putString(prefix+"_"+i, list.get(i));

    editor.putInt(prefix+"_size", list.size());
    editor.commit();
}
```

To retrieve it:

```
public static List<String> readList (Context context, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int size = prefs.getInt(prefix+"_size", 0);

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        data.add(prefs.getString(prefix+"_"+i, null));

    return data;
}
```

And to actually use it:

```
List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
animals.add("cat");
animals.add("bear");
animals.add("dog");

writeList(someContext, animals, "animal");
```

And to retrieve it:

```
List<String> animals = readList (someContext, "animal");
```

**If you are not limited to use SharedPreferences, consider using [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)!**

Comment: hey brother i am using your code but retrieving null values because of this code:  data.add(prefs.getString(prefix+"_"+i, null));