# storing existing file into internal memory and get path

Tags: android, android-file

I have one xml file which i want to store it in a internal memory and later one i just need a path to that file to access it.

I have an existing file so there is no need to write a file inside my program i just want to store it in such a way that user accidently can not delete that file and the application can read it by accessing its path.

*Note: I am using third party library which accepts file path only. i dont want to store it in SD Card*

I tried `AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();` but this doesn't give relative path when required. I tried `/data/data/com.bcl/external.provider` and copy my external.provider file in application package but didnt work.

so how to get a path where i can store file and get its path.

Comment: Check my answer if you look for [internal storage file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150597/save-an-arraylist-of-strings-to-shared-preferences/12150626#12150626)

Comment: Where would i put my existing external.provider file before reading it |

Comment: You don't need to change anything in the code, just test it.

Comment: its saying file not found at `data/data/com.bcl/file/external.provider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write the file inside the files folder in `data/data/package_name/` and read it from there. This folder is in internal storage so user won't be able to read the file. You can get the path using `getFilesDir()` which will give you as `data/data/package_name/files/`

Comment: so i have to store my whole big xml content into a string then got to write into it ?