# using Androids sharedpreferences for multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Im trying to save an ArrayList containing multiple ArrayLists of Strings into the sharedpreferences of Android. I also want to support API level 8 and higher and if possible avoid the use of databases. Do I need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150597/save-an-arraylist-of-strings-to-shared-preferences) or is there a easier method to simply save my ArrayLists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JSON for this purpose. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

There are also nice JSON tutorials around the web.