# How to save 2 string file to internal storage in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, storage, internal

I put in 2 texts then pressed save and saving internal storage. Press List button reading List.java there are saving data's in list. so I pressed MainActivity button and i put in 2 texts again. But this time List.java's previous data has lost. Only one row data's in listview. How can i fix this problem. I want to dynamically add 2 items in internal storage in listview. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940672/how-to-save-internal-storage-via-custom-adapter-in-android-list

Thanks for help.

[image: example app screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940672/how-to-save-internal-storage-via-custom-adapter-in-android-list

Comment: why you are not using local database for that.??

Comment: ohkk.. then use local database for storing data and retriving it..

Comment: ok i'll try. but any idea for my code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31368/discussion-between-segi-and-user1303250)

Comment: do you have any example of this discussion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Custom view for List row and implement that view into List View.

Here are some of the links for Custom List

- [Example-1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
- [Example-2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: i want add items to internal storage listview thx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the array list to Internal Storage as a file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150597/save-an-arraylist-of-strings-to-shared-preferences) answer or code below,

For writing to file,

```
    try {
   //Modes: MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE
   FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("lines.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
   DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
   dout.writeInt(text_lines.size()); // Save line count
   for(String line : text_lines) // Save lines
      dout.writeUTF(line);
   dout.flush(); // Flush stream ...
   dout.close(); // ... and close.
}
catch (IOException exc) { exc.printStackTrace(); }
```

For reading it,

```
    FileInputStream input = openFileInput("lines.txt"); // Open input stream
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
int sz = din.readInt(); // Read line count
for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) { // Read lines
   String line = din.readUTF();
   text_lines.add(line);
}
din.close();
```