# Put some data into the android program

Tags: java, android, bundle

I'm new on Android programming.

I want to create some ArrayLists and put them into the program. When I close or pause the program they must be stored. Until the program uninstalled.

How can I store them in the program.

Can I use savedInstanceState?

Comment: read this link [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: depending on how many items you want to store, SharedPreferences for smaller amount, SQLite Database for larger amount.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Comment: using Shared preferences only  use this code [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150626/2377760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Shared preferences for store data and get data for more details see offical documentation on below  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

and this link for sample tutorial for shared preferences http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1):

Ways to store array List .

**Option 1.** I referred to this link [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

After API 11 the SharedPreferences Editor accept Sets. You could convert your List into a HashSet . When your read it back, convert it into an ArrayList . **Check the above link for complete explaination and code .**

```
//Retrieve the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();
```

**Option 2.**  If you have no. of arrayLists and instead of using option one ,you can save the data in a table using sqlite .[Sqlite](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAD&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html&ei=nkjEUYeMFsbqrQex7IHABA&usg=AFQjCNGHrlZI8DewY8QwqR2vRa37N2GJpg&sig2=daqKfKZajgCdaQD_5Q_8AA&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bmk) is preferred when you have bulky and relational data.
you can check this [sqlite tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/&ei=pEnEUZyKL4nzrQfvp4EY&usg=AFQjCNGHYjhcTpp8TnA-OpE-E68dV-97rA&sig2=sWuaU4Z3e3GYmpN8gWHZsw&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bmk)

**Option 3.** Use static arraylists .Static variables retain values but not for very long .Its not a good practice to use static variables .

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link on developer site

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Your data storage options are the following:

**Shared Preferences**

Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

**Internal Storage**

Store private data on the device memory.

**External Storage**

Store public data on the shared external storage.

**SQLite Databases**

Store structured data in a private database.

**Network Connection**

Store data on the web with your own network server.

Comment: Please include information from that link in your answer. If the link dies, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQLite install that comes integrated with Android. This will persist until the user uninstalls/wipes their data [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) [This tutorial has good examples](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to store data persistent to use till you uninstall the application:

Store it in DB
Store it in Shared Preference File.

As you said you are new to android, I would prefer you to use SharedPreference.

Declare the preference object like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(context, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To store the value in the key using

```
prefs.edit().putString(KEY, "Value to be stored").commit();
```

To get the value use

```
prefs.getString(KEY, DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

If the KEY doesn't have a value-pair then the DEFAULT_VALUE is returned.

Comment: can I add an ArrayList to SharedPreferences?

Comment: No. But you could probably think about a work around to fit in the list of options available to store.