# How to save an ArrayList <List>

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, sharedpreferences

I I have ab ArrayList which is containing ArrayLists, they are again containing lists. One of Strings and one of Views. How could i save This root list to Shared Preferences or in any other was? Here is an overview:

```
           MotherList
                | 
                .
          DaughterLists
            /       \
           /         \
    ListOfViews  ListOfStrings
                .
                .
```

Comment: is this an android question?

Comment: Why do you want to save an `android.view.View` in a `SharedPreferences`? I don't understand what it means.

Comment: Why are you even holding on to a list of views? This sounds like a recyclerview scenario...

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7057845/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21794419/642706)?

Comment: Convert Object to string and save it in shared preference

Comment: @RedDragon, you can use to "LinkedHashMap" for implementing your idea

Answer (score 0):

Here are all of methods about put data in SharedPreferences:
  putBoolean(String key,boolean v)
  putInt(String k,int v)
  putFloat(String k,float v)
  putLong(String k,long v)
  putString(String k,String v)
  putStringSet(String k,Set v)

But there is a open-source frame called ASimpleCache can solve it:

save:
   ACache acache = ACache.get(Context);
   acache.put("key",your-root-list);
get:
   acache.getAsObject("key");

Answer (score 0):

**Store Arraylist Using Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit=prefs.edit();

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(your Arraylist Name);
edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
edit.commit();
```

**Retrieve Arraylist from Shared Preferences**

```
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
List<String> sample=new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Comment: You can convert it to JSON String and store the string in the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I suggest you to use GSON , for serializing and deserializing your list. By this way you can save it on your `SharedPreferences` easily.

1. First convert your `ArrayList<List>` object to **JSON** with help of **GSON Converter**

   ```
   String myArrayListAsJSON = new Gson().toJson(myArrayList); // you will pass your arraylist variable to toJson() method
   ```
2. Save your **JSON Object** as `String` on your `SharedPreference`

   ```
   SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY_FOR_YOUR_APP",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   Editor edit=prefs.edit();

   edit.putString("myListKey", myArrayListAsJSON); // we will put our list hat serialized with GSON here
   edit.commit();
   ```
3. Re-use your list at any place/time of your application. You will just need to deserialize your JSON that you saved on your `Shared Preferences`

   ```
   SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY_FOR_YOUR_APP",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   String myListAsString = prefs.getString("myListKey","default_value");
   ArrayList<List> yourObject = new Gson().fromJson(myListAsString, YOUR_MODEL.class);
   ```

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

You can use **GSON** in your app by adding this line to your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

You can find more detail and example on [GSON Github Page](https://github.com/google/gson)